# Finding out whether an NSTableView row has been viewed by the user

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

Is there a way to get notified that a user has actually seen an NSTableView row (meaning it was scrolled into view when the table view was frontmost).

An example of this would be a messaging app. How does such an app would track what messages have been viewed by the user?

Comment: I think most apps would catch the load of the newest messages, then force a scroll to the top, then mark all current messages as read. If you wanted to be really explicit you could catch scroll events and check which messages are clearly all on screen?

Comment: Yes, that is what I did. I am setting the status of every message that appeared on a screen (I know that it appeared because a table cell view was created for it) to "Read" in the database and it seems to work well. Thank you.